# Prevents UISearchDisplayController from hiding the UiTable

Tags: objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Im new to objC and Im currently experimenting on UISearchDisplayController. Basically I have an array of string as my data and I use UISearchBarDisplayController to filter my data. Im able to retrieve the correct values when I enter my searchText into the search bar. However, the tableView disappears when my searhBar text is empty.

Would it be possible to prevent the tableView from hiding in this such case. What I want is to just to display all the values in my array in the table if the searchBar text is empty.

I checked the hidden/alpha/frame property of the table and tried to fix my issue here but I think Im in the wrong path here. I'm thinking if i need to subclass the UISearchDisplayController and override the [setActive:YES animated:YES];? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried subclassing the UISearchDisplayController and override the [setActive:animated:] method and set some properties of the tableView just to make it appear on the screen. But still no luck, can't figure this out. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working with UISearchBar and UITable.
So here are the scenarios I encountered.

1. Display the the UITable when the searchBar is clicked.
2. UITable shows all the data from my plist when searchText is empty.
3. UITable shows filtered results from my plist that matches the searchText.
4. Dismiss the keyboard on press of the search button but don't disable the cancel button on the searchBar.
5. Remove the UITable when cancel button is press.

I don't have the animation for showing the table for now but this works for me. Also, I allowed the user interaction and scrolling on my table during search so no overlay needed in this case. Glad its working now. :)

I created a sample project for those who might need. Here is the [link](https://github.com/shoktong29/TheSearchBar.git). Apologies for a messy code and leaks issues. Just posted this to share. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should recieve an event for any change to the search parameters, including when the string is empty.

If you change your implementation of that delegate method to check if the string is empty, you can return the original data instead of the filtered data. This should achieve what you're asking for without the need for subclassing.

Comment: The issue im having is that the tableView is not visible as soon as the searchController becomes active, instead I only see the black overlay. And it disappears when the search string is empty. I tried calling the [searchBar: textDidChange:] inside [searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:] but i cant get the table to show when the searchBarTextDidBegin method is called. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try by always leaving a zero-space width characters in the search textfield :

```
static NSString* zsp = @"\u200B";

//In the UISearchBarDelegate

- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if(searchBar.text.length == 1 && [text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        searchBar.text = zsp;
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```